# Angular JS : select element doesn't function in the modal window

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I am trying to make the select element work in a modal window which is opened from the main page. Following code would help to understand the exact scenario :

home.html
{................
 ...........

```
  <div class="pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-with-text" ng-click="addModalOpen = true">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add New Item
    </button>
  </div>
...............
...............
  <div ng-controller="mrsri.controller.AddCtrl"
       class="modal fade"
       ng-class="{'in' : addModalOpen}"
       ng-include="'resources/mrsri/views/createNewRI.html'">
  </div>
............
```

}

createNewRI.html

{

```
.............
<div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header"></div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form name="createRIForm" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Class Code</label>
       <div class="ri-col-sm-6">
         <select name="classCode" class="form-control" required ng-model="inventory.classCode" ng-options="item.className for item in CCs">
         <option value="">Select a CC..</option>
         </select>
      </div>
....................
....................
    </form>
```

}

addctrl.js

{

```
angular.module('mrsri.controller').controller({'mrsri.controller.AddCtrl' :
  [ '$scope', 'mrsri.service.ClassCodeService', 'mrsri.service.LocationService', 'mrsri.service.InventoryService',
         function($scope, ClassCodeService, LocationService, InventoryService) {

     $scope.inventory = {};
     $scope.selectedClassCode = {};

.............
.............
     ClassCodeService.getAllCCs(function(data) {
          $scope.CCs = data;
     });

     $scope.addInventory = function(inventory) {
        $scope.inventory.classCode = $scope.selectedClassCode.classCode; //this does not work at all. While debugging in the developer tools and typing either of the above expressions returns 'undefined'
     InventoryService.addInventory($scope.Inventory, function(data) {
     });
....................
```

}

From the main page - home.html, if the user clicks on the "Add New Item" button, a modal window opens up (createNewRI.html - its controller is AddCtrl.js). The modal window has a huge form to be filled in by the user, and then finally clicking on the Save button on the modal window should save the details into the DB. There are several things from the above code which are not clear to me. I am just a week old with Angular JS.

1. In the createNewRI template - is there anything wrong with the way I am populating the options ? I tried multiple ways like : using "item.classCode as item.className for item in CCs" OR "item.className for item in CCs track by item.classCode" etc. Tried out these options so that whenever I select an option from the drop-down, I can get the value of that option in my controller and then I can pass that value to my service finally.
2. In the AddCtrl.js : In this controller, i have put in my comment in the above code. I tried many different ways to get the value but it is not working. Just to add here, that I have many other fields on this form, I am able to get the values for all the other fields as they are not drop-downs, but the issue is only with the drop-down.

Could anyone please help me out with this ? Or please let me know if my questions is not clear enough to answer ?

Comment: I am not really sure of the exact problem, so please dont really go by the title of this problem. Thanks. Any help would be appreciable and would definitely help me to work further with Angular JS.

Comment: Can someone please give some pointers on this problem ?

Comment: I tried more ways to get this working, but it looks like I am seriously missing something basic here. Anybody can please guide me here ?

Comment: Is my question correct to answer ? Can anyone please provide some pointers please ?

Comment: Hi, can someone please provide some pointers on the problem that i have stated above ?